# Does the link-rollback is needed or not for mysql pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am moving my codes into using pdo since its much safer with sql injection protection. I would like to confirm is below codes acceptable. Is the  $link->rollback(); place at the right place or should it be place after every query in the else section? Another challenge why whenever there is any error at of the query it just show the final catch error message not at the very query which has error?

```
try {
         $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.dbDatabase.';host='.dbHost;
        $link = new PDO($dsn, dbUser, dbPassword );
        $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
    }
    $link->beginTransaction();
    $rollBackStatus="False";
    try{

        $selectQuery1 ="Select t*********!=:tn"; 
        $selectQueryResult1 = $link->prepare($selectQuery1);
        $selectQueryResult1->bindParam(':tn', $tn);
        $selectQueryResult1->execute();
        $n1=$selectQueryResult1->rowCount();

        if($n1>0)
        {
            echo "TN ".$tn." Already Exist.</span>";
            $rollBackStatus="True";
        }

        $insertQuery2a =  "Insert Into tblTit Set ". 
                           "tID=:ID, ".
                           "fieldName='tn',".
                            "userID=:uID, ".
                            "dateTimeInsert=now() ";

            $insertQueryResult2a = $link->prepare($insertQuery2a);
            $insertQueryResult2a->bindParam(':ID', $ID);
            $insertQueryResult2a->bindParam(':uID', $_SESSION['userID']);

                if($insertQueryResult2a->execute()){

                }
                else{
                     echo "Error Adding Audit tn: " . $insertQueryResult2a->errorInfo() . "</span>";
                     $rollBackStatus="True";    
                }
               if($rollBackStatus=="False"){

                  $link->commit();  
               }
    }
    catch(PDOException $pe)
    {
        $rollBackStatus="True";
        die("Error in update catch :" . $pe->getMessage());
        $link->rollback();
    }
    $link=null;
```